How do I bypass ADB Error Message and/or delete OEMs
I have a TCL Android phone. I keep getting error messages when attempting to use ADB to debloat my phone. I would love to know why my commands aren't working and what the correct ones to enter are. I was inputting the following commands
First;
adb shell pm list users

Then these exact commands in any given order as I have attempted this several times over now;
pm uninstall -k --user 0 com.facebook
pm uninstall -k --user 0 com.facebook.appmanager
pm uninstall -k --user 0 com.facebook.services
pm uninstall -k --user 0 com.facebook.system

These are the error messages which come up in return.
Exception occurred while executing 'uninstall':
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Bad user number: com.facebook
    at android.os.UserHandle.parseUserArg(UserHandle.java:489)
    at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerShellCommand.runUninstall(PackageManagerShellCommand.java:2012)
    at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerShellCommand.onCommand(PackageManagerShellCommand.java:234)
    at com.android.modules.utils.BasicShellCommandHandler.exec(BasicShellCommandHandler.java:97)
    at android.os.ShellCommand.exec(ShellCommand.java:38)
    at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.onShellCommand(PackageManagerService.java:25476)
    at android.os.Binder.shellCommand(Binder.java:950)
    at android.os.Binder.onTransact(Binder.java:834)
    at android.content.pm.IPackageManager$Stub.onTransact(IPackageManager.java:5092)
    at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.onTransact(PackageManagerService.java:8829)
    at android.os.Binder.execTransactInternal(Binder.java:1184)
    at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:1143)

I hope my efforts in tracing down those error messages will prove helpful for you.
I've found on another post on this website that a quick fix would be to uninstall secure folder. I haven't been able to find any trace of a secure folder on my TCL Android. Nor did I see "disable monitoring permissions" in my dev settings which I had seen written as a quick fix on another post on this website.
Any help would be much appreciated I have 32GB to myself on my work and personal phone and the OEMs are taking up 15GBs of those.

You have only posted the error message and stack trace but forgot how include the exact command that causes it. How should we know what mistakes you made on entering the command if you don't show it to us? Also it would be good to know the device model and Android version. Last but not least why do you post the same error message twice - one time was more than enough?

Im so sorry that I wasn't able to tell the difference between two walls of error messages. If you read closely im asking what the correct command to enter is. If that code feedback does indeed indicate that I made a mistake that would be lovely of you to share, so that I could know that I should include all the 7 different ways that I imputed the command. Why do you expect me to be a genius in this field and instantly know everything needed when asking the question without having been given ANY formal training. How very demeaning of you.

Please keep calm. I understand that you might feel attacked, but on the other hand, troubleshooting Android devices is very difficult because Android is open-source, and manufacturers can and do customize their Android OS, thus what you saw and tried for other device models might not work on your device (I assumed you read the one specifically for Samsung devices). This is why we expect the asker to give information as detailed as possible in the first place since extended troubleshooting to get enough details may also take time before getting an acceptable solution.

Please remain calm Andrew. If you'd like to expect something of any other human being, you need to first inform them of that beforehand. You may not expect any other human being to do ANYTHING that you haven't informed them that their expected to do, understood?
